# woocommerce shows cart is empty in firefox,after adding the products to cart

Tags: php, wordpress

woocommerce shows cart is empty when products are added,in firefox browser after redirecting to cart page. But works well in other browsers like Internet explorer and chrome. And, displays the number of items in the cart in all browsers,before redirecting to the cart page.

```
global $woocommerce;

$data=explode(',',$_POST['productids']);
try
{
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($data);$i++)
{
    if($data[$i]>0)
    {           
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart($data[$i],1);
    }
}
$my_cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
echo $my_cart_count;

}catch(Exception $e){echo $e;}

 echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location="'.WC()->cart->get_cart_url().'";</script>';
```

And further, if I login and do the same process, everything works correctly.

Comment: What happens if you do var_dump($_POST['productids']); die(); ? Does it contain the value(s) you would expect (ie. a comma delimited list of product ids)?

Comment: yes, it has product id values, if i do var_dump($_POST['productids'])

Answer (score 2):

Possible reasons :-

1. Cookies may be enabled in Firefox
2. Caching problem in your side or server side
3. WordPress memory limit may be exceeded.
     Edit your wp-config.php file and enter something like:

   ```
     define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
   ```
4. Put secret keys in your wp-config.php

   [WP Secret key generate](https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/)
5. Please check this article [Woocommerce: Solving the “Cart is Empty” issue](http://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-solving-cart-empty-issue/)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem the cart was working in chrome and firefox but not in maxthon browser.. so it was quiet evident it was a browser issue not the script.. so I struggled and finally found that cookies were disabled in maxthon browser and when I enabled it , the cart started working properly..

so you can try the same in your case for firefox..

you can do following steps to enable cookies for firefox..

- Select firefox Drop-down menu
- Select Preferences
- select Privacy
- Set "Firefox will:" to Use custom settings for history.
- Check "Accept cookies from sites" to enable cookies.
- click Ok...